# How can access req.session value in ejs template

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on **nodejs** with **ejs**. I have maintain session using **req.session in js** file. I have access that session variable in **ejs template**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass it from the outside like this:

```
res.render(viewName, { session: req.session });
```

Then the `session` variable should be accessible inside the template.

Comment: what if it’s a redirect?